# Find all items which are subsets of an item

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, db.databases

I have a problem that I think should have been studied. I am looking for algorithms for it.

Each item is a set of key-value pairs.
Let $x$ be an item and $F$ be a set of items.

Each key and each value can appear multiple times.
The number of possible keys and possible values can be arbitrary large.

We are given $x$ and $F$. We want to find all those items $y$ in $F$ such that $y.val \subseteq x$.

For example,

$x = \{(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4)\}$

$F= \{$
$(A, \{(a,1)\}), $
$(B, \{(a,1), (b,2)\}),$
$(C, \{(a,1), (b,3)\}),$
$(D, \{(b,2), (c,3), (d,4)\}),$
$(E, \{(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4)\}),$
$(F, \{(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4), (e,5)\}),$
$(G, \{(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (e,5)\})$
$\}$

The answer is:
$A$ yes, $B$ yes, $C$ no (right keys, wrong values), $D$ yes, $E$ yes (exact match),
$F$ no, $G$ no.

Has this problem been studied?

The problem seems similar to finding features from a DNA sequence or detecting plagiarism in a document.

Comment: Please state the computational problem that you want to solve without code. For example: I am given input [the description of what is given], and I want to compute [the description of what you want to compute]. Check other questions for examples.

Comment: Will there generally be a total order on the set of values? $\hspace{2.51 in}$ Will there generally be a total order on the set of keys? $\:$

Comment: @Kaveh I thought code would be helpful because I'm unfamiliar with the vocabulary used in theoretical computer science. Regardless here's a stab...  **Given an item defined by an unknown number of key value pairs and a feature set of items defined the same way, find the items in the feature set that are a subset of the given item.** Even help defining this problem would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Will you answer my two previous questions? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer The keys will all be text values and are unique to a sigle item (aka definition). The values are text or numeric values.

Comment: @RickyDemer and Kaveh - I understand this is not the type of problem you guys enjoy solving but could you point me in some direction that would take me a step closer to solving it?

Comment: @wroscoe, I think the down-votes are not because of the problem you want to solve but because of the style you have stated your problem. Remember, this is a *theoretical* computer science Q&A. You need to state your problem in mathematical language and be clear and accessible. For questions about algorithms, you should not assume any particular programming language. I will edit the question based on your comment, feel free to edit further.

Comment: ps: Asking for code is off-topic here. If you want code you should ask on [SO]. Btw, the question might be more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope. I can migrate it there if you want.

Comment: there is so much extraneous information it seems. why does it matter these are key-value pairs? you have a set $S$ and a collection of sets $\{T_1, ..., T_n\}$, and you want to output all $T_i$ which satisfy $T_i \subseteq S$. the key word for you is hashing.

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for the edit. This is much cleaner.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Could you suggest something more specific than hashing. I've looked into hashing but couldn't find anything directly relevant.

Comment: @SashoNikolov : $\:$ I would have mentioned that if the extra information was necessarily extraneous. $\;\;$ In the original question, the space of keys and the space of values have a simple total order, and each key can only occur once per set. $\;\;$ Those features may allow a faster algorithm. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Oh come on..hash each pair in $x$ and store them in the hash table. now for each item in $F$, hash each of its pairs and check if it is equal to a pair in $x$. The expected running time is linear in input size.

Comment: It *is* linear time in the input size: for each item $y$ in $F$ check if all pairs in $y$ are in the hash table. ps: this is not really research-level and should be migrated to [cs.se].

Answer (score -1):

The most straightforward answer I can think of, but unsure about running times:

```
def find_matching(d, f):
      matching = []
      dSet = set(d.items())
      for k in f:
        if set(f[k].items()).issubset(dSet):
          matching.append(k)
      return matching
```

Comment: 6 character edit requirement $\:$ gaaah $\;\;\;$

Comment: This is not [SO]. For questions about algorithms you should not assume people know any particular programming language. Please explain your algorithm in plain English or pseudo-code.